# Let gevent stop polling when one socket succeeds

Tags: python, gevent

I'm using gevent to poll several sockets just to see if one of the specified ports is open. How to make gevent stop polling if one of the sockets succeeds?

```
import gevent
from gevent import socket

vm_ip = "10.3.12.2"
ports = [22, 16120, 16122]
def fn(port):
    while True:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(5)
        result = s.connect_ex((vm_ip, port))
        s.close()
        if result == 0:
            return

jobs = [gevent.spawn(fn, port) for port in ports]
gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a flag in your while loop, and turn off that flag when you found the result. Greenlets are coroutines, not threads, so no problem in doing this:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent import socket

vm_ip = "10.3.12.2"
ports = [22, 16120, 16122]
found = False
def fn(port):
    while not found:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(5)
        result = s.connect_ex((vm_ip, port))
        s.close()
        if result == 0:
            found = True
            return

jobs = [gevent.spawn(fn, port) for port in ports]
gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=30)
```